# solr fuzzy search with edit distance above 1

Tags: solr, java-11, edit-distance

Enviornment- java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS, solr-8.9.0

I have the following field declaration for my Solr index:

```
<field name="Field1" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="author" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="Field2" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
```

Field type:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Solr-core has been created using command : ./solr create -c fuzzyCore
The .csv file used to indexed the data is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z684x2GKsSQWGAdyi6O4uKit4a96iiuh/view

I understand that "Lucene supports fuzzy searches based on the Levenshtein Distance, or Edit Distance algorithm. To do a fuzzy search the tilde, "~", symbol at the end of a Single word Term is used.

~ operator is used to run fuzzy searches. We need to add ~ operator after every single term and can also specify distance which is optional after that as below."

```
{FIELD_NAME:TERM_1~{Edit_Distance}
```

Since 'KeywordTokenizer' keeps the whole input as a single token and I want each word to be searchable, so 'StandardTokenizer' is used.

request looks like as mentioned below :

```
    curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/fuzzyCore/select" --data-urlencode "q=author:beaeb~' AND Field1:(w1 x)" --data-urlencode "rows=20"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":14,
    "params":{
      "q":"author:beaeb~' AND Field1:(w1 x)",
      "rows":"20"}},
  "response":{"numFound":12,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"bbaeb",
        "Field2":"o",
        "id":"f8fbb58d-9e0d-47b2-aa3c-e3920e25a7d1",
        "_version_":1746912583192936455},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"beabe",
        "Field2":"p",
        "id":"7d73e7ba-8455-4eb4-818f-1e19b1d35a22",
        "_version_":1746912583244316680},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"baeeb",
        "Field2":"n",
        "id":"b4e86fc3-7ecc-407b-b638-88d167a66934",
        "_version_":1746912583292551181},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"beaea",
        "Field2":"o",
        "id":"131ad4de-eaa2-47b8-b58b-e690316eed1c",
        "_version_":1746912583314571267},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"bbaeb",
        "Field2":"q",
        "id":"d034e66c-a302-4b24-a186-5a2bafecab40",
        "_version_":1746912583392165900},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"beacb",
        "Field2":"n",
        "id":"c0ab3e48-2b2d-438d-8cc2-1acfcf6efde8",
        "_version_":1746912583490732036},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"aeabe",
        "Field2":"m",
        "id":"4472ec5d-eace-446f-b1d6-c8911be24368",
        "_version_":1746912583266336776},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"baeab",
        "Field2":"q",
        "id":"b4c24da3-9199-4eba-a8a3-e30fc17d9167",
        "_version_":1746912583274725377},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"aeaea",
        "Field2":"n",
        "id":"bb17bc26-e392-4fed-ae46-bbdd40af0ac0",
        "_version_":1746912583294648329},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"aeceb",
        "Field2":"p",
        "id":"5e5cfe21-ff19-464f-8adf-8b5888c418e4",
        "_version_":1746912583296745472},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"baeab",
        "Field2":"p",
        "id":"54a3c8e6-137d-47c3-9192-a5ed1904dc55",
        "_version_":1746912583357562889},
      {
        "Field1":"x",
        "author":"aeeeb",
        "Field2":"m",
        "id":"200694a0-6248-49fd-8182-dac79657e045",
        "_version_":1746912583385874444}]
  }}
```

,
The above request is not retrieving output as 'author:bebbeb',although there is author:'bebbeb' is present in data with Field1:w1. This can be
verified with following two commands

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/fuzzyCore/select" --data-urlencode "q=author:beaeb~' AND Field1:w1"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4,
    "params":{
      "q":"author:beaeb~' AND Field1:w1"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Although output of following command is

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/fuzzyCore/select" --data-urlencode "q=Field1:w1"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"Field1:w1"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "Field1":"w1",
        "author":"bebbeb",
        "Field2":"p",
        "id":"4356dff2-ab93-4bab-a4dc-1797db38240c",
        "_version_":1746912583504363523}]
  }}
```

so I tried to post everything you need to understand my problem. Any ideas? Why author:'bebbeb' is not resulting as output for input:beaeb~

Comment: You have `numFound: 12` - the default number of entries being returned is 10, unless you give a different `rows` argument. What you're seeing is not the complete result set - the two last entries hasn't been included, since you never asked for them. Append `rows=12` (or any larger value) to your query string to get all the entries.

Comment: @MatsLindh.Thankx for reply! The last two entries is not having author value: 'bebbeb'. I have updated the complete result-set in the questions, still the author value 'bebbeb' is not present. Also the link of .csv file is present in the question. This can be used to index the data.

Comment: I reproduced your case locally and by doing your exact queries I can see the document with "author": "bebbeb" in the search results

Comment: @ Seasers  thanks for the reply! I have done the following steps 1) ./solr create -c fuzzyCore ... 2) Defined field-type  3)Indexed document using command: curl "localhost:8983/solr/fuzzyCore/…" --data-binary @simulate_et.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'. 4) Retrieval query .. Is it correct or there is another way to index the .csv file? What I am doing wrong? Have you changed the solr configurations or its running on default? What is your solr version? I run the case again, and Still the same result, not able to find "author": "bebbeb" in the search results.

Comment: @Seasers i have done it again and still getting the same result...Any idea where i am doing wrong? Have u changed default configurations of solr to reach out the result?

Comment: @user595014 Sorry for the late reply. Actually, I manually indexed only a few documents using the Solr GUI and was able to retrieve "bebbeb" in the search results. All your steps look correct. In fact, it seems that when few documents are indexed it works fine, while when many documents (thousands) are indexed (using GUI or curl command) something is wrong. Lucene debugging may be required.

Comment: @Seasers Can u please direct me to some link dictating about, if number of documents increases than there is problem/ noise in lucene indexing.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging Lucene we discovered that there is a parameter called `maxExpansions` set to 50 by default, which could be extended to 1024.

However, looking at the Solr code, we can see that the `FuzzyQuery` constructor is only called twice and always uses the default `maxExpansions` value (for performance reasons); **this means fuzzy searches take at most the 50 most similar terms and discard the others.** That's why when many documents are indexed and most of the terms are similar (as in your case), some documents may not be returned.

A Solr open-source contribution would be needed to expose this parameter and make the use of this feature more flexible (allowing different values to be set).

Comment: Is there any get-around here so that I can get a complete result set?

Comment: @user595014 Not for the moment. It seems that source code changes are required.